# In a locally compact Hausdorff space, is the sum of two compactly supported functions also compactly supported?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $f, g:X\to\mathbb C$ be functions with compact support. The support of $f$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{supp}(f) = \text{the closure of }\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}
\end{equation}
Then does $f+g$ also has compact support?

I know that $\operatorname{supp}(f+g)\subseteq \operatorname{supp}(f)\cup\operatorname{supp}(g)$. But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Hint: the union of two compact sets is compact.

Comment: @user744868 Oh thanks! I didn't need the LCH assumption.